# Adding the elements of a Vector without using `reduce` or `apply`

Tags: vector, clojure, reduce

So I am trying to re-implement the `reduce` method, so it can add a couple of numbers that normally can be done using `reduce`, like:

```
(reduce + [1 2 3]) ;; 6
(newRd + [1 2 3])  ;; 6
```

So I thought maybe it can be done using a recursive function that adds the first element of the vector every time it is called and do it again for the rest of the vector. Something like this:

```
(defn newRd [list]
  (let [sum 0]
    (if (not= 0 (count list))
      (+ sum (first list))
      (newRd (rest list))
      )
    )
  )
```

I think I am not doing local storing correctly. Any suggestion or maybe a better approach?

Comment: [Lets TDD Clojure core reduce](http://www.lispcast.com/lets-tdd-clojure-core-reduce)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are two mistakes here in your code:

1) you don't add your current sum to the recursive call result

2) you should return zero when the list is empty

corrected variant:

```
(defn newRd [list]
  (let [sum 0]
    (if (not= 0 (count list))
      (+ sum (first list)
         (newRd (rest list)))
      sum)))
```

in repl:

```
user> (newRd [1 2 3 4])
10
```

next, you can update it a bit:

first you don't really need the sum in `let` statement, since the `sum` always = 0

second, there is a lib function `empty?` to check if list is empty.

```
(defn newRd [list]
  (if-not (empty? list)
    (+ (first list)
       (newRd (rest list)))
    0))
```

but remember: clojure doesnt'do tail call optimization, so it is easy to cause stack owerflow with a long list:

```
user> (newRd (repeat 1000000 1))
StackOverflowError   user/newRd (form-init289434844644272272.clj:73)
```

so it's preferable to use loop/recur

```
(defn sum-list [list]
  (loop [list list sum 0]
    (if (empty? list)
      sum
      (recur (rest list) (+ sum (first list))))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (sum-list (repeat 1000000 1))
1000000
```

the other option is to make the function itself tail recursive:

```
(defn newRd [list sum]
  (if-not (empty? list)
    (recur (rest list) (+ sum (first list)))
    sum))

user> (newRd (repeat 1000000 1) 0)
1000000
```

then you can add the additoinal arity, for not to pass the second parameter in every call:

```
(defn newRd
  ([list] (newRd list 0))
  ([list sum]
   (if-not (empty? list)
     (recur (rest list) (+ sum (first list)))
     sum)))
```

Comment: `(if-not (empty? list) ... )` is better as `(if (seq list) ... )`.

Comment: don't think it's better. since `empty?` is just `(not (seq coll))`, i think it was added to the library on purpose: the readability of it is much better ("if not empty list" looks nice and natural to me, better then "if seq list")

Comment: I sympathise, but the docstring for `empty?` says *Please use the idiom (seq x) rather than (not (empty? x))*.

Answer (score 2):

Further to [leetwinksi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35147136/1562315) ...

You might as well implement `new-reduce` (camel case is not idiomatic) in general:

```
(defn new-reduce
  ([f init coll]
   (if (seq coll)
     (recur f (f init (f init (first coll))) (rest coll))
     init))
  ([f coll]
   (if (seq coll)
     (reduce f (first coll) (rest coll))
     (f))))
```

Then

```
(new-reduce + [1 2 3]) ;; 6
```

This is more or less what the source code for `reduce` looked like until recently, if you stripped chunking out.

The two-argument version that you use leans on the three-argument version, which you can `recur` on directly, without an explicit `loop`. This entails passing `f` each time, but that's what it used to do. Presumably it's faster to carry an extra argument than to work in a local scope.