# How can I define a function with uncertain argument in clojure

Tags: clojure, reduce

I am wondering how to define a function with an uncertain argument in clojure. Here is an example:

```
(reduce + [1 2 3 4]) => 10
(reduce list [1 2 3 4]) => (1 2 3 4)
(reduce inc [3]) => 3
```

I want to define the reduce function `(reduce func coll)` which can apply the func to the first two elements in coll, then apply the func to the result of the first two elements and the third element, until all the elements are used. I am puzzled that is it different with the source code of reduce? I have no idea how to define this function so far. Is there anyone can help me to figure out this problem or give me some tips? I will appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, you are asking to do this:

> apply the func to the first two elements in coll, then apply the func to the result of the first two elements and the third element,

That is exactly what `reduce` does:

```
user> (reduce list [1 2 3 4])
(((1 2) 3) 4)
```

The list of the first two is `(1 2)`. Then, apply the `list` function to this result and the next element, which is `3` and you get `((1 2) 3)`. And continue until all elements are used up.

I suspect you are not asking your question correctly or clearly.

--

I see now you are asking not how to create the function you want that is different from reduce but rather how to actually implement reduce yourself?

If that is the case, typically functional designs like this involved recursion, where you split your sequence into a head and a tail, process it, and then recur on the tail, which then splits it again into a head and tail, until there is no more tail left.

Comment: Hi Johnbakers! I am sorry to confuse you about my question. Now I know what I want to know. I think the exact question should be how to define the reduce function which can do such implements. The purpose of the task is let us know how the reduce works. I have figured out how to define the reduce function using recur. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Might be good to contrast `reduce` with `apply`. Here's the best definition I could find for `apply`:

> apply explodes a seqable data structure so it can be passed to a function that expects a rest parameter. For example, max takes any number of arguments and returns the greatest of all the arguments.

This definition comes from the 'Brave and True' [book](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/#apply)

`reduce` does not make sense with only one argument whereas `apply` works for any number of arguments - it applies all of the arguments to the function. Hence in your last example `inc` is given 3 and returns 4 if you use `apply` rather than `reduce`.

The function used with `apply` must take 'any' number of arguments, denoted by the a `&` in the formal parameters definition. So `apply` just grabs all values inside the sequence and gives them to the function. Actually `apply` is quite greedy with this 'grabbing' so what follows the function can in fact be a series of arguments not contained within a structure.

In a way `reduce` is stricter about the way it uses its function. The function must take two arguments (or none for an edge case) because that is how `reduce` uses it. The result of calling the function on the first two arguments is then passed to the third and so on, much as you described it in your question.

**Edit** A more comprehensive definition of [`apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178770/definition-of-function-apply)

Comment: Hi Chris! I know that reduce is stricter and I run the code: (apply inc [3]), then I got the result 4. But now I want to define my-reduce. Here is the task requirement.

Comment: . Here is the question description: <br/> Write, without using any higher order function, the function reduce. Write (reduce f coll) to take two arguments, a function of two arguments, f, and a collection, coll, that applies the function to the first 2 items in the collection, then to the result and the third argument, until all the elements are used. For example, (reduce - [1 2 3 4]) = (- (- (- 1 2) 3) 4) = -8

Comment: If the collection does not contain any items, the function must accept no arguments, and reduce returns the result of calling the function with no arguments. If the collection has only 1 item, the item is returned and the function is not used.

Comment: I added 'or none' to my answer thanks - but that's just an edge case. Implementing reduce was recently asked and answered on SO. My hint would be to use recursion. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145965/adding-the-elements-of-a-vector-without-using-reduce-or-apply

Comment: The definition of `apply` is too restrictive. The function need only accept the number of arguments supplied, including the final sequence. For example, `(apply (fn [a b] (+ a b)) (range 6 8))` yields `13`.

Comment: Are you saying the Brave and True definition is too restrictive? There's more to it than 'seqable' data structure? I'm hoping my description was too vague to make it as a definition. This would make a good SO question in its own right.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Yes. The final argument is always a sequence, but the function need not have a rest argument. You can avoid using `apply` in such cases. Perhaps you should. But you needn't.