# Definition of function `apply`

Tags: clojure

To me `apply` is one of the more difficult functions in Clojure. I'm looking for a good definition of its mechanics - what exactly it does, especially regarding how it 'grabs' arguments that it feeds to the function it is supplied as the first parameter. For instance this definition:

> apply explodes a seqable data structure so it can be passed to a function that expects a rest parameter. For example, max takes any number of arguments and returns the greatest of all the arguments.

, from the 'Brave and True' [book](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/#apply). Is there more to it than that? It seems to me that `apply` can be given many 'free' arguments (arguments not in any data structure) and will supply them to the given function. What are the rules for how `apply` grabs params for its function? What makes it stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` only explodes the last argument. So, for instance, this:

```
(apply f 1 2 [3 4] 5 [6 7 8])
```

is equivalent to this:

```
(apply f (concat [1 2 [3 4] 5] [6 7 8]))
```

All I've done in this step is take every argument except the last one and put them into a sequence (here I've used a vector, but the exact type doesn't matter), then concatenated that sequence with the last argument (which was already a sequence).

Simplying further, we get this:

```
(apply f [1 2 [3 4] 5 6 7 8])
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
(f 1 2 [3 4] 5 6 7 8)
```

To better understand the behavior of `apply`, you can think of it as working like this:

```
(defn apply [f & args]
  (.applyTo f (seq (lazy-cat (drop-last args) (last args)))))
```

Just for completeness, this implementation differs from the actual implementation in two ways:

1. Empty argument list

   ```
   ;; actual implementation
   (apply +)
   ;=> ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/apply

   ;; my implementation
   (apply +)
   ;=> 0
   ```
2. Laziness

   ```
   ;; actual implementation
   (apply apply == (range))
   ;=> StackOverflowError

   ;; my implementation
   (apply apply == (range))
   ;=> false
   ```

Comment: I'm a bit confused because that looks like 5 arguments and the last argument is `[6 7 8]`

Comment: Yes, that's right, the last argument is `[6 7 8]`. The `apply` function simply takes the three elements of that last argument, sticks them onto the end of all the other arguments, and calls the function with the resulting sequence of arguments.

Comment: So it goes to the last argument and then grabs arguments backwards. Until it finds any function? Where does it stop in this example: `(apply swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f args)`. At `f` or at `swap!`?

Comment: Well it is `f` of course. But what if args was like `f1 f2 f3 [f4 f5]`, where all the `f`s are functions? How would `apply` know that `f` is the function that needs to be applied to the numbered `f`s?

Comment: `apply` always applies its *first* argument. Whether the other arguments are functions makes no difference; they will be passed to that first argument as values regardless. The reason `apply` can do this is because in the end, all functions are values just like any other values (numbers, lists, maps, etc.), so it can just get the first of its arguments and apply that, without regard to specifically *what* the other arguments are.

Comment: I am confused because `swap!` has grabbed all the way to `[:contacts]`, and then `args` is applied to `f`, and then the result of that is what is updated in `:contacts`. It is this kind of '`apply` in the wild' that is difficult to understand.

Comment: No; if you call `(apply swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f args)` and `args` is, for instance, `[:foo :bar :baz]`, that expression is equivalent to `(swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f :foo :bar :baz)`. No trickiness going on whatsoever. Then the resulting value of `app-state` would be essentially `(update-in @app-state [:contacts] f :foo :bar :baz)`.

Comment: How about if `args` was `f1 f2 [f3 f4]`? `apply` grabs backwards and when it reaches `[:contacts]`, which is not a function, it knows it has gone too far and chooses `f` as the function it is going to apply the (function) arguments to.

Comment: I think where you're getting confused is about how `apply` "decides" when to stop grabbing backwards. Rather than slurping arguments until it reaches something that is a function or maybe until it finds something that isn't a function, it simply keeps slurping until there's only one argument left. Then, assuming that argument is a function (which it must be, otherwise an error will be thrown), it applies that argument to the sequence it created from slurping all the other arguments together.

Comment: But `swap!` has not started to be evaluated yet, so [:contacts] is still there to be slurped, and then the function `update-in` etc.

Comment: Does the simplified implementation of `apply` I added help in your understanding?

Comment: Somehow all the things between `apply` and `f` are not going into the `apply` function call. I can understand slurping and recognising that `f` is a function. But if instead of `[:contacts]` there was another function, then that would be the function that is chosen to go with `apply`, and the arguments would be `f :foo :bar :baz`.

Comment: That's the thing: there is no "recognizing" going on. As you can see from my implementation of `apply`, the only arguments that are treated differently from the others are the first one (which I have called `f`, but could be anything) and the last one (which gets "exploded"). The "slurping" just means taking all those *other* arguments (the ones in between the first and last) and sticking them onto the beginning of that last argument, which is assumed to be a sequence. Then that entire resulting sequence is passed to the first argument as an argument list to a function call.

Comment: `(apply f1 app-state f2 [:contacts] f :a :b [:c])`. The slurping starts at [:c] because it is the last and it is a vector. It keeps slurping till it finds the first one which is `f1`.

Comment: Yes, so you get `(f1 app-state f2 [:contacts] f :a :b :c)`.

Comment: So `apply` gets all the args and `swap!` is the function. Translating `f1` and `f2` back again gives `(swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f :a :b :c)`. I was fixated on `f` being the function, when all the time it was `swap!`.

Comment: Yep, that's right! :) Does that answer your question, then?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work and patience.

Answer (score 2):

just take a look at its source:

```
(defn apply
  ([^clojure.lang.IFn f args]
     (. f (applyTo (seq args))))
  ([^clojure.lang.IFn f x args]
     (. f (applyTo (list* x args))))
  ([^clojure.lang.IFn f x y args]
     (. f (applyTo (list* x y args))))
  ([^clojure.lang.IFn f x y z args]
     (. f (applyTo (list* x y z args))))
  ([^clojure.lang.IFn f a b c d & args]
     (. f (applyTo (cons a (cons b (cons c (cons d (spread args)))))))))
```

where `spread` is the following:

```
(defn spread
  [arglist]
  (cond
   (nil? arglist) nil
   (nil? (next arglist)) (seq (first arglist))
   :else (cons (first arglist) (spread (next arglist)))))
```

so, it takes as many arguments as you provide, making a list of them, expecting the last one to be a sequence, which will be concated to the previous items. And it doesnt matter whether the one of your args, except last one, is a collection, it won't be flattened.

`(apply f a b c d e f g [h i j k])` fill call a function with params `a b c d e f g h i j k`

that's all it does.

Obviously it's up to you to make it correspond the applied fn args, if your function takes two arguments, `(apply f [1 2 3 4 5])` will cause an exception.

Comment: Good point that it doesn't have to be a 'function with a rest parameter'. As you say a two argument function will work fine given two params. It is a dynamic language after all. Was that the only problem with the definition? Would you say 'seqable data structure' was technically correct, or more just haphazard language?

Comment: `sequable data structure` is totally technically correct. I emphasizes, that it takes anything that can be converted into a seq (not only clojure's own data structures, but also java collections and arrays, and anything you make sequable)

Comment: The last example is wrong. The last argument *must* be a sequence. I think you mean `(apply f [1 2 3 4 5])`.